# Google Chrome - Failed GET ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I am developing a website which loads html from a template page then loads content from XML. for instance these are called in the document.ready function

```
$.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "template.html",
                dataType : "html",
                success : function(html) {
                    var ndoc = document.createElement('html');
                    ndoc.innerHTML = html;
                    page = $('body', ndoc);
                    $('body').html(page.html());

                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "XML/content.xml",
                        dataType : "xml",
                        success : function(xml) {
                            page = $(xml).find('chisiamo').find('dialogue')[0];

                            setupPage(page);
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

This works well in Firefox and Safari. But in Chrome i get a 'Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when it tries to load template.html. How can I solve this problem? thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of that?

Comment: A screenshot? this is the exact string I get in the Chrome console: 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/***/Dropbox/CorpoMusicale/template.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224017/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-in-chrome-why

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to modify my query to allow it to be successful in chrome?

Comment: @Lorenzo - have you tried using an absolute URL, e.g. `http://localhost/path/to/file/template.html`?

Comment: You need a webserver. You cannot just open files from the disk

Comment: No luck with that. Is there a way to make my website work with a stock chrome even through only locally?

Comment: @Lorenzo - Yes. See zerkms's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Google Chrome with this arguments :

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: I need to make this website work locally in google chrome. I am aware of the arguments you posted, but isn't there a way to change my request so it works with a standard Chrome without startup options?

Comment: I don't think because it's a 'security'.
Have you try to put your files in an http server ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a Chrome Web App and set the permissions in the manifest to allow it access to read files from the file:// scheme.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

Comment: can you please be more specific? I am really just approaching the whole compatibility thing and am pretty much clueless in this case.

Comment: I managed to build the manifest and get the first HTML request working, but cannot still load from XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add permissions to the page you are requesting in the manifest.  Also try using $.getJSON instead ;)