# jsTree not populated in Browser like IE, Google chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jstree

I am trying to bind xmlData into jsTree but the data is not being populated into jsTree (other than Mozila firefox).

**jsTree is populated with sample data in  Mozila firefox but not in other browser**

What have I missed in following code?

jsTreeDemo.html file:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Use jsTree</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Employees_xml_flat.xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(xmlData) {
                $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
                    "xml_data" : {
                        "data" : xmlData
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Sample xml file as follows:

> ```
> <root>  
>     <item id="4" parent_id="0" state="open">  
>         <content><name><![CDATA[Charles Madigen]]></name></content>  
>     </item>  
>     <item id="192" parent_id="4">    
>   <content><name><![CDATA[Ralph Brogan]]></name></content>               
>     </item>  
>     <item id="295" parent_id="192">    
>         <content><name><![CDATA[Bhushan Sambhus]]></name></content>  
>
>
>     </item>  
>     <item id="294" parent_id="192">    
>         <content><name><![CDATA[Betsy Rosenbaum]]></name></content>  
>     </item>  </root>
> ```

**Mozila firefox version 11.0 ** :   jsTree populated well

**Internet explorer version IE8 **:

[image]

**Google Chrome version 18.0.1025.162 m ** : Nothing is display :: Error coming on console
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/VaibhaV/JsTreeDemo/files/Employees_xml_flat.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

Browser compatibility issue?
Code issue?
Xml format issue ?

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the console to see if there are any errors caused by the AJAX request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Getting error message : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: + throws Neither data nor ajax settings supplied.

Comment: Have you had a look at `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me assume that the url to `Employees_xml_flat.xml` is correct. Then the variable *xmlData* should be a string containing the data of your xml sample file.

Also let me assume that you put the "themes" folder that goes with the jstree package in the same folder as your `jquery.jstree.js` file.

The first thing I notice is that your sample xml file does not contain a `</root>` element at the end of your sample xml file!! If your sample xml file does not contain this element, your jstree will keep showing "Loading...".

Furthermore, instead of obtaining your sample xml file using ajax, I put it manually into a string (+ `</root>` at the end of the file). My results show this your sample xml file should have the correct file format this way and the code should work in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer. Here is my test html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Use jsTree</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Employees_xml_flat.xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(xmlData) {
                $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
                    "xml_data" : {
                        "data" : xmlData
                    },
                    "plugins" : [ "themes", "xml_data" ]
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="treeViewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### UPDATE

I took a look at it again, based on your comment. Looking at the jstree documentation, the data is to be added as an XML string:

> data
>
> A XML string (or false if not used). Default is false.
>
> Specifies the content to load into the container and convert to a
>   tree.

Currently, since you have selected the dataType in your ajax call to be 'xml', the return object is a XMLObject and not a string. To have the ajax call return a plain text string, set the dataType to 'text'. I have updated the piece of code above and it should work :)

The line

```
var xmlstr = xmlData.xml ? xmlData.xml : ( new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
```

is thus not needed anymore. But even if you would want to put keep this line in, it should work properly. Tested it in Chrome, IE and firefox.

---

### IE8 update

I have taken a look if I got the same result as you did in IE8. Opened the exact html file as in the above code, except that I replaced jquery.js with: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js. The result of this test can be seen in [this image](http://i40.tinypic.com/2qn4ks9.png). As you can see, the code works, also in IE8.

What version of jQuery are you using? Are you using version 1.7.2.? Could it be that your jQuery.js file is corrupted in some way?

---

### Another update

The solution to the error caused in Chrome can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224017/origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-in-chrome-why). This should definitely fix your problem in Chrome. As for IE7 and IE8: you have to add a DOCTYPE to your html page. I.e.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: @ 1 themes and jquery.jstree.js in same folder

@ 2 </root> present in original file, missing here :), added . Answer is not acceptable from my side. plz provide me good solution.

Comment: @VaibhaV I have looked at it again and I think I found your problem. You basically have to change your dataType in your ajax call to 'text' (See my edit of my answer)

Comment: Changes xml  to text then Got error message on Internet explorer 8 :( Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sun, 22 Apr 2012 18:32:51 UTC


Message: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
Line: 16
Char: 3008
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/VaibhaV/Documents/Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace/JsTreeDemo/files/jquery.js

Comment: I verified above code in IE8 and it works. See my update of this answer.

Comment: replaced jquery.js by jQuery.min.js Tree displayed in IE8 :) whats issue with jquery.js ?  from where I will get proper(not corrupted) jquery.js ? How to find out in future that particular js is corrupted?  In my xml every nodes state=close still All nodes are expanded in IE8 whats wrong :( and tree not display in Google chrome :(

Comment: I do not know what the issue is with your jquery.js (you didn't provide me with information about your version or how you got it). You can get the most recent version of jQuery on http://jquery.com/. In production you usually get the minimized version. 
Finding our where the problem in a js file is, is just a matter of looking at the errors and debugging. For instance, the error in your previous comment said: Line: 16 in jquery.js . I don't know why they're expanded in IE8 (might be a jstree bug?). What version of Chrome are you using/what error do you get?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded latest version of jquery-1.7.2.min.js. In my xml every nodes state=close still All nodes are expanded in IE8 whats wrong ? Added Image of jsTree behavior on IE8 plz go through it.

Google chrome error is XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/VaibhaV/JsTreeDemo/files/Employees_xml_flat.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer. I think this should solve all your problems to get it working in all of your browsers :)

Comment: Thanks for reply IE related issue solved :) . Google chrome issue as it is XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/VaibhaV/JsTreeDemo/files/Employees_xml_flat.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. :(  I am only one step behind to accept this answer :)

Comment: Either run it on a webserver (you can install xampp or wampp as a local webserver on your computer), or start Chrome with the option '--allow-file-access-from-files' set.

Comment: :) Thanks for reply Google chrome issue also solved at my machine: JsTree display properly. But what about N number of user we can't say to everyone start your browser with --allow-file-access-from-files ---- http://softwareroxer.blogspot.in/2009/07/how-to-start-google-chrome-with-user.html ---- Is there alternative way ?

Comment: If you upload the files on a webserver (locally or remotely) the problem will automatically be solved. The user shouldn't get this error.