# jquery $.ajax dilemna - revision required

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

**Update**
I just tested the link to my example and... damn thing works.! I am not convinced??? Any comments still welcome.

I have just updated my browsers and Chrome rejects my (previously working) ajax call to a simple text file containing html. Here is my current bare-bones code:

```
var stringData = $.ajax({ url: 'digz/index/'+$(this).attr("id")+'.txt', async: false }).responseText;
var $newItems = $(stringData);
alert($newItems.filter('.element').length); // FF & IE OK but Chrome = '0'
// there are few things here and I have tested with them rem'd out
$('#container').isotope( 'insert', $newItems ); // std. isotope form
```

The Chrome console gives me:

```
Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.   
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...file path/name... ] Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

And the pointer in jquery - around line 8472 in ver 1.9.0

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

I have a stripped down version of my project here:
[Null return on Ajax](http://www.buddhamind.info/br/left_test.htm)

I figure the ajax line is the problem and needs revision. I have tried a lot of alternate permutations but there so many options and my experience here is limited.

Comment: See if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866062/1331430

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - thanks for the links. You posted between my save and update. See above. Yes, I realise that I need to run my local version in a server environment, using Chrome. FF & IE are quite happy with the local relationship. I will try the  "--allow-file-access-from-files" and see how that works. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're opening the file using the `file:///` scheme. Chrome won't allow direct access to the hard disk's files if doing so.

As my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866062/1331430) mentions, there's an workaround for it running Chrome with this flag:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

However, the most optimal solution, in case you plan to serious development using your local machine, is to install Apache locally to serve content through `http://localhost`. This lifts the `file:///` scheme restrictions as all browsers will load the page using the `http` protocol.

These are often used for local development: [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/), [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [BitNami](http://bitnami.com/).

Comment: @Arfa No prob, I also use EasyPHP. `=]` Just don't forget to open the page through `http://localhost` as `file:///` will fail in Chrome without the allow file access flag.